# Rewriting metadata into .jpg file by using Swift 2.2 OS X

Tags: swift, macos, metadata

I'm try rewrite metadata from JPG file. I want addition one keyword to metadata. Xcode don't give any errors, but file not changed.
Here is my code:

```
var pathToOpenFile:NSURL?
```

Next I write path from file to variable "pathToOpenFile".
If user pushed ENTER button into NSTextField, then work action:

```
    @IBAction func endEditKeys(sender: AnyObject) {
       if (pathToOpenFile != nil) {
           let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(pathToOpenFile!, nil)
           let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary;
           let exifDict = imageProperties.valueForKey("{IPTC}")  as! NSDictionary;
           var Keywords:[String] = exifDict.valueForKey("Keywords") as! [String];
           Keywords.append("ANY")
           exifDict.setValue(Keywords, forKey: "Keywords")

           let type = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource!)
           let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(imageSource!)
           let mutableData = NSMutableData(contentsOfURL: pathToOpenFile!)
           let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData!, type!, count, nil)
           let removeExifProperties: CFDictionary = exifDict 

             for i in 0..<count {
                CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination!, imageSource!, i, removeExifProperties)
             }

           CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination!)
      }
    }
```

Can you help me, why it isn't work (not change metadata)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
It is working, just need rewrite .JPG file in end.

```
if let _ = try? mutableData!.writeToURL(pathToOpenFile!, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite) {
          //  if you need, do anything. For example "print ("Savig file")"
        }
```